# Slope of line when Correlation = 0 is not always 0?

Tags: regression, correlation

Practicing for a statistics final in 2 days. When is the following true?

```
The correlation between the variables x and y is zero.

However, the best curve that relates x to y is not a horizontal line.
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean "the best curve [...] is _not_ a horizontal line"?

Comment: The best curve that relates x to y is one that is close the scatter dots on scatter diagram. Also zero correlation may show other type of relationship such as quadratic, circular etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correlation measures the strength of linear association between X and Y. This doesn't rule out other, *nonlinear*, forms of association. Here's an example where $y \propto x^2$, over the range $x \in [-5, 5]$. The correlation between the two variables is zero, but the relationship is obvious.

[image]

More generally, see [Anscombe's quartet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe's_quartet), which illustrates how various configurations of X and Y can end up with the same linear correlation but have very different relationships.